# AJAX Filter Posts. Changing select options to button group

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to search and filter posts by category and have it working by using the below code.

But instead of using a select dropdown I'd like to change this to a button group.

**Current working code**

```
<form action="/" method="get" autocomplete="off" id="product_search">
<input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search Knowedge Hub" id="keyword" class="input_search" onkeyup="fetch()">
<select name="cat" id="cat" onchange="fetch()">
    <option value="">All Categories</option>
    <?php
    $terms = get_terms(array(
        'post_type' => 'cpt_knowledge',
        'taxonomy'   => 'category',
        'hide_empty' => true,
    ));

    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        echo '<option value="' . $term->term_id . '"> ' . $term->name . ' </option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

**Ajax Call**

```
    add_action('wp_footer', 'ajax_fetch');
function ajax_fetch() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function fetch() {

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    action: 'data_fetch',
                    keyword: jQuery('#keyword').val(),
                    pcat: jQuery('#cat').val()
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    jQuery('#datafetch').html(data);
                }
            });

        }
    </script>

<?php }
add_action('wp_ajax_data_fetch', 'data_fetch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_data_fetch', 'data_fetch');
function data_fetch() {
    if ($_POST['pcat']) {
        $product_cat_id = array(esc_attr($_POST['pcat']));
    } else {
        $terms = get_terms('category');
        $product_cat_id = wp_list_pluck($terms, 'term_id');
    }
    $the_query = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => - 1, 's' => esc_attr($_POST['keyword']), 'post_type' => array('cpt_knowledge'), 'tax_query' => array(array('taxonomy' => 'category', 'field' => 'term_id', 'terms' => $product_cat_id, 'operator' => 'IN',))));
    if ($the_query->have_posts()):
        while ($the_query->have_posts()):
            $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <?php knowledge::render(); ?>
    <?php
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
    die();
}
```

I think I need to use something similar to the below, but need to change the ajax call `pcat: jQuery('#cat').val()` to onclick or something like that.

```
<div class="c-button-group" name="cat" id="cat" onchange="fetch()">
<button value="">All Categories</button>
    <?php

    // Product category Loop

    $terms = get_terms(array(
        'post_type' => 'cpt_knowledge',
        'taxonomy'   => 'category',
        'hide_empty' => true,
    ));

    // Loop through all category with a foreach loop
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        echo '<button class="c-button" value="' . $term->term_id . '"> ' . $term->name . ' </button>';
    }
    ?>
```

Could anyone help please?

EDIT.

I've got closer with this code [link](https://gist.github.com/paddywinc/ff185c07ec4efae0cf919a1dfd881fc0) The search bar is still working and an Ajax call is being made when clicking on the category buttons, but the posts aren't refreshing.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I hadn't taken into account that you also had a launch of the fetch() function from the keyboard event on the "keyword" input. And I made a mistake in the JQuery code because I was not used to using `jQuery` (I use `$` instead)

Comment: And with the new code you provide, (on the link) if you display datas with `console.log()` what do you have...?

Comment: My apologies for not being clearer. The console log shows all of the posts.

Comment: No problem. So what's wrong..? Data not showing in "datafetch" div...?